# $(e^x-1-x)^z$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to be able to write $$(e^x-1-x)^z$$ as a power series, so since $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
I can write $e^x-1-x$ as 
$$(e^x-1-x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}$$
Now, other than trying to expand using brute force, How can I look at the power series expansion of $(e^x-1-x)^z$ for some integer $z$?

Comment: Maybe use trinomial theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Note:* As far as  I  know, there is *no closed formula* for the coefficient of $x^n$ of $(e^x-1-x)^z$. But, at least you can write the coefficient as *sum of multinomial coefficients*.

The following notation is convenient. Let $[x^n]$ be the *coefficient of* operator denoting the coefficient of $x^n$ in a power series $A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$. So,
$$[x^n]A(x)=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k=a_n$$

We claim:

> The following is valid for $z\in\mathbf{N}$
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]&(e^x-1-x)^z=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_z}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In order to show (1) we calculate:

> \begin{align*}
> [x^n]&(e^x-1-x)^z\\
> &=[x^n]\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^z\\
> &=[x^n]\left(\sum_{k_1=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k_1}}{k_1!}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(\sum_{k_z=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k_z}}{k_z!}\right)\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{n=2z}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\frac{x^{k_1+\dots+k_z}}{k_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot k_z!}\right)\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{n=2z}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\frac{1}{k_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot k_z!}\right)x^{n}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{n=2z}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\frac{n!}{k_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot k_z!}\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{n=2z}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_z}\right)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{{k_1+\dots+k_z=n}\atop{k_1,\dots,k_z\geq 2}}\binom{n}{k_1,\ldots,k_z}
> \end{align*}